# asyncio get result from coroutine

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a task make communication between coroutines with help asyncio  and python3.
Please tell me how to do it,if one coroutine,in while tru cycle , return value at different intervals, and the other coroutines receives this data

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def write(future):
    i=0
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        future.set_result('data: '.format(i))
        i+=1

def got_result(future):
    print(future.result())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.Future()
asyncio.ensure_future(write(future))

future.add_done_callback(got_result)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Use `asyncio.Queue`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. but if I'm going to use Queue,how I can read it on the event,not constantly checking the queue.It will must work on the principle of the method " asyncio.Future().add_done_callback(func) " using queue

Comment: End user code should never call `.add_done_callback` -- it's too low level.
Just do `while True: await queue.get()`.

Comment: I'm understood, thank you

Comment: If you'll make an answer for your question with explained solution -- it might be useful for others :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found with the help of the asyncio.Queue()

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_work(task, work_queue):
    while not work_queue.empty():
        print(task)
        queue_item = yield from work_queue.get()
        print('{0} grabbed item: {1}'.format(task, queue_item))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    asyncio.async(get_work(task, work_queue))

# @asyncio.coroutine

i = 0
async def do_work(task, work_queue):
    global i
    print(task)
    while work_queue.empty():
        work_queue.put_nowait(i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        break
    # asyncio.async(do_work())
    print("Dfgdfg")
    asyncio.ensure_future(do_work(task, work_queue))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_obj = asyncio.Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    tasks = [
        asyncio.async(do_work('Run do_work', queue_obj)),
        asyncio.async(get_work('Run get_work', queue_obj))]

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.run_forever()
```