# Regarding the asyncio module, how to get the return value of the sub-coroutine?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The current event loop of the coroutine has been opened. Inside a coroutine object, create a new coroutine object and register it in the event loop.

**Question:** How can I get the return value of the `sub-coroutine`?

I want to get the return value of `func_first`

```
import asyncio
import time


async def func_first(values):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('out: func_first')
    return values


async def func_second():
    s = asyncio.create_task(func_first(100))
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('out: func_second')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    s = time.time()
    loop.run_until_complete(func_second())
    print('TIME:', time.time()-s)
```

Comment: You can use `await` on the task object returned by `asyncio.create_task()` to wait for and retrieve the value returned by the coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, just add await s to your print statement.  In fact, it's even easier than that: don't bother with creating a task; just await the function and print the value directly.  This code shows both methods:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def func_first(values):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('out: func_first')
    return values

async def func_second():
    s = asyncio.create_task(func_first(100))
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('out: func_second', await s)

async def func_third():
    print('out: func_third', await func_first(101))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    s = time.time()
    loop.run_until_complete(func_second())
    print('TIME:', time.time()-s)
    loop.run_until_complete(func_third())
    print('TIME:', time.time()-s)
```

Result:

```
out: func_first
out: func_second 100
TIME: 3.062396764755249
out: func_first
out: func_third 101
TIME: 5.09357476234436
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186964/asyncio-get-result-from-coroutine)

`asyncio.Queue` can get data, it seems that I still don't know much about this module. lol